# Qt creator doesn't launch in Linux Mint for QT 5.5.1

Tags: qt, linux-mint

I used the offline installer to install QT 5.5.1 (32 bit) in Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.2 (32 bit) in VirtualBox. Install was OK. Then QT creator doesn't launch. QT 5.5.0 works OK. Any ideas anyone?

From the command line it says could not initialize GLX.

Comment: Try to install `libgl1-mesa` packages.

Comment: I tried that. No help. I think it's got something to do with the VirtualBox video drivers is my suspicion.

Comment: With VirtualBox 3D acceleration for the display turned off for the virtual machine it works fine.

Comment: This issue still occurred for me after verifying 3D support was disabled on Ubuntu 16.04 with vSphere